# WSO2 API Manager returning RunTime Error

Tags: api, request, wso2

I have an API in WSO2. When I try to test it in the store with valid parameters via GET, it returns the following error message:

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
    <am:code>101504</am:code>
    <am:type>Status report</am:type>
    <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
    <am:description>Send timeout</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

I have already searched and tried a lot, but with no success, always returning the same error. Don't know if helps, but the api that I try to access is a PHP file.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I have identical apis to this one, changing only the response, that are working properly. Even if I erase the `php` file that the API is pointing, the error keep coming.

**EDIT:**
I changed the code in Management Console, in Metadata>List>APIs:

```
{"production_endpoints":
{"url":"http://site/myapi.php","config":
{"format":"leave-as-is","optimize":"leave-as-
is","actionSelect":"fault","actionDuration":30000}},
"sandbox_endpoints":
{"url":"http://site/myapi.php","config":
{"format":"leave-as-is","optimize":"leave-as-
is","actionSelect":"fault","actionDuration":30000}},
"implementation_status":"managed","endpoint_type":"http"}
```

to this:

```
    {"production_endpoints":
{"url":"http://10.20.40.189/ConsultaAutorizacaoCadPos.php","config":null},
"sandbox_endpoints":{"url":"http://10.20.40.189/ConsultaAutorizacaoCadPos.php","config":null},
"implementation_status":"managed","endpoint_type":"http"}
```

And this error message vanishes. But this new one appears:

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
<am:code>303001</am:code>
<am:type>Status report</am:type>
<am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
<am:description>Currently , Address endpoint : [ Name : admin--myapi_APIproductionEndpoint_0 ] [ State : SUSPENDED ]</am:description>
```

**EDIT:**  this error message is appearing just sometimes. Most of the time the request takes long time to run and then returns nothing( *no content* )
Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Please enable wire logs and update the question with the logs. http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html

Comment: Based on the error code, it is a connection timeout. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Error+Handling

Comment: @Bhathiya Where can I access this path? Sorry for the question, I'm a really begginer in using wso2 and there still some points that are very confusing to me.

Comment: @Pubci Yes, it's like the wso2 itself refuses to make the request. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: The log file is `<APIM_HOME>/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log`. Btw, what do you mean by "I changed the code in carbon"?

Comment: @BHA I meant the Management Console, in Metadata>List>APIs and then changed the code above

Comment: Changing that has no effect because those are metadata. The runtime artifact is a file in `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployments/synapse-conf/default/api/`

If you provide that runtime artifact file of your API and the logs I asked, I might be able to help.

Comment: @BHA I wasn't able to find the file. Have any step-by-step on how to find it?

Comment: Check  `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployments/server/synapse-configs/default/api/`